# In itext how to set spacing BETWEEN Paragraphs to zero

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a problem where when html is converted into PdfElements using

```
elementsList = XMLWorkerHelper::parseToElementList(html, css)
```

It's working however, I've noticed that

```
<div>line1<br/>line2</div>
```

gets parsed into 2 different Paragraph elements where as

```
<div>line1 line2</div>
```

results in a single element.

Is there possibly a way to reduce the spacing between 2 paragraphs such that it becomes the same as the spacing of lines in a naturally overflowing single paragraph?

I know about:

```
p.setPaddingTop(float x)
p.setSpacingAfter(float x)
p.setSpacingBefore(float x)
```

setting a negative value for x indeed does decrease the spacing however I'd like to avoid doing that because of font size and line spacing adjustment issues, is there a sure fired way to absolutely make sure they are the same?

Comment: Do you have control over the source html?  Removing the <br/> is the first thing that comes to mind.  Otherwise, you're either at the mercy of parseToElementList, or you'll have to tweak things out post processing as you've indicated.

Comment: I can but that might cause issues, I still want <br/> to overflow as usual and everything else to be inline